# After I used keep-alive in Vue, I couldn't get the DOM data correctly with Ref

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, ref

I used keep-alive to cache A and B pages in Vue, used the same component in the page, and then used `ref` in the component to get the current width of the component. It was normal when I first entered any page, but when I switched from page A to page B or from page B to page A for the second time, the width of the printed component was 0. Later, I found that it output. Is the width of the component of the first page, because it is not displayed, so the width is 0. Is there anyway to solve it?

Vue 2.6.10

This is component.

```
    <div class="waterfall" ref="cardsBox">

    console.log('cardBox',this.$refs.cardsBox.offsetWidth);
```

Pages A and B use

```
<waterfall :list="articles" horizontal="3" vertical="2">
    <template v-slot="props">
        ......
    </template>
</waterfall>
```

Comment: Do you try execute it in the nextTick? this.$nextTick( () => console.log('cardBox',this.$refs.cardsBox.offsetWidth); ). Or show the example code

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I tried the method you gave me. When I switched the page, I executed this. $nextTick () => {console. log ('cardBox', this. $refs. cardsBox. offsetWidth)} in activated (). It could print the current width correctly, but when I executed the method, if it jumped from A to B, it printed page A to width. If it jumps from B to A, it prints B pages to width.

Comment: I tried to use key to distinguish different pages from components, but it still hasn't been solved.